# Subset a dataframe to include samples from another file

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I currently have a count matrix data.frame where the rownames are the genes and the colnames are the sample names

```
head(colnames(countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse))
[1] "UB01.31YE" "UT38.78EE" "YW49.74CE" "OB13.46DD" "OT35.78PE" "KE51.98JE"
head(rownames(countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse))
[1] "Gnai3" "Pbsn"  "Cdc45" "H19"   "Scml2" "Apoh" 

head(countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse[,1:10])
      UB01.31YE UT38.78EE YW49.74CE OB13.46DD OT35.78PE KE51.98JE YB40.88ZA UI68.54DC GB09.27EE QI98.56TC
Gnai3    88.608    67.174   104.042   103.504    80.314    81.985   104.550    58.628    70.957    89.278
Pbsn      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000
Cdc45    10.121     6.637    12.057     5.356    13.340     3.309     7.987    83.508     8.491    93.227
H19      43.613     2.044   152.882     0.095     0.455     0.325     1.660     0.278     0.313     0.037
Scml2     0.342     0.000     0.283     0.517     0.000     0.000     0.000     2.262     0.684     4.787
Apoh      0.000     0.781     0.204     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.071     0.000     0.059
```

The above data.frame includes 963 samples but I want to subset the samples from that data/frame to the samples that I have in a separate excel sheet. Which looks like below. The sample names are the same but have a "-" instead of ".".

```
> head(pdac_samples)
         V1
1 GT34-87JE
2 QT33-82OE
3 KT30-82ZE
4 UT38-78EE
5 SO33-16DD
6 CD10-05ZE
```

How would I go about subsetting `countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sub` to replace the `-` with `.`, then find the names in common, and use standard `data[row, column]` subsetting:

```
dot_names = sub(pattern = "-", replacement = ".", pdac_samples$V1, fixed = TRUE)
names_in_common = intersect(names(countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse), dot_names)
countmatrix_subset = countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse[, names_in_common, drop = FALSE]
#       UT38.78EE
# Gnai3    67.174
# Pbsn      0.000
# Cdc45     6.637
# H19       2.044
# Scml2     0.000
# Apoh      0.781
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse = read.table(text = '      UB01.31YE UT38.78EE YW49.74CE OB13.46DD OT35.78PE KE51.98JE YB40.88ZA UI68.54DC GB09.27EE QI98.56TC
Gnai3    88.608    67.174   104.042   103.504    80.314    81.985   104.550    58.628    70.957    89.278
Pbsn      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000
Cdc45    10.121     6.637    12.057     5.356    13.340     3.309     7.987    83.508     8.491    93.227
H19      43.613     2.044   152.882     0.095     0.455     0.325     1.660     0.278     0.313     0.037
Scml2     0.342     0.000     0.283     0.517     0.000     0.000     0.000     2.262     0.684     4.787
Apoh      0.000     0.781     0.204     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.071     0.000     0.059', header = T)

pdac_samples = read.table(text = '         V1
1 GT34-87JE
2 QT33-82OE
3 KT30-82ZE
4 UT38-78EE
5 SO33-16DD
6 CD10-05ZE', header = T)
```

Comment: I receive this error:

`> countmatrix_subset = countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse[,sub(pattern = "-", replacement = ".", pdac_samples$V1, fixed = TRUE)]
Error in `[.data.frame`(countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse, , sub(pattern = "-",  : 
  undefined columns selected`

Comment: Try `pdac_samples[, "V1"]` instead of `pdac_samples$v1`.  It could be it is a matrix, not a data.frame.

Comment: @RicVillalba The error does say `[.data.frame`. More likely there are entries in the `pdac_samples` matrix that are not in the `countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse` object.

Comment: @mmpp Try again with the new edits. My best guess if you have entries in the `pdac_sample` data frame that are not column in the countmatrix.

Comment: `countmatrix_subset = countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse[,dot_names]
Error in `[.data.frame`(countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse, , dot_names) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: 94/102 sample names are present in`countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse`

One thing to add, is that `pdac_sample` is not a data.frame but a .txt file which I imported like this:

`pdac_samples <- read.table("pdac_ptx_models.txt")`

Comment: `read.table` returns a data frame, so `pdac_samples` is indeed a data frame. `"pdac_ptx_models.txt"` is a text file, `pdac_samples` is a data frame.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the error. I think the code should work. Can you make your example more reproducible?

Comment: @GregorThomas I added 1:10 column and rows for `countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse`

Comment: You call it a "matrix data frame". Could you please check `class(countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse)` and confirm whether it is a `matrix` or a `data.frame`?

Comment: @mmpp It would also help if you could share sample data where there is a non-empty expected result. The first 10 columns that you shared don't have any matches in the first 6 rows of `pdac_samples` that you shared.

Comment: `class(countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse)
"data.frame"`

I include 4/6 sample names that are present in `(countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse)`

Comment: Ah, I had a typo, using `dot_names` in the last line where I should have had `names_in_common`. Thanks for providing data so i could check the code.

Comment: Though I certainly only see 1 name in common. If you think there are more, please point them out.

Comment: @GregorThomas The first four are in `countmatrix_clean_cl_mouse`